# Convert timestamp to readable date/time PHP

Tags: php

I have a timestamp stored in a session (1299446702).

How can I convert that to a readable date/time in PHP? I have tried srttotime, etc. to no avail.

Answer (score 477):

Use PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function.

Example:

```
echo date('m/d/Y', 1299446702);
```

Comment: You can go through to https://www.epochconvert.com/programming/php for epoch or timestamp to human readable date using PHP.

Answer (score 99):

strtotime makes a date string into a timestamp.  You want to do the opposite, which is [date](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).  The typical mysql date format is `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`  Check the manual page for what other letters represent.

If you have a timestamp that you want to use (apparently you do), it is the second argument of `date()`.

Comment: it would be good note that I passed in my current date as follows: `echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($current_date_variable);`

Comment: is there no command to convert an timestamp to their datetime standardisation becouse i converted an datetime to an unix timestamp but in my database it is still an datetime i wil try this but i still find it weird that there is no specific command for it

Answer (score 89):

I just added H:i:s to Rocket's answer to get the time along with the date.

```
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', 1299446702);
```

Output: 03/06/2011 16:25:02

Answer (score 75):

```
$timestamp = 1465298940;
$datetimeFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

$date = new \DateTime();
// If you must have use time zones
// $date = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Helsinki'));
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
echo $date->format($datetimeFormat);
```

> result: 2016-06-07 14:29:00

Other time zones:

- [Africa](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.africa.php)
- [America](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php)
- [Antarctica](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.antarctica.php)
- [Arctic](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.arctic.php)
- [Asia](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)
- [Atlantic](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.atlantic.php)
- [Australia](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.australia.php)
- [Europe](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php)
- [Indian](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.indian.php)
- [Pacific](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.pacific.php)
- [Others](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

Comment: Lately, I've been quite partial to `$date = (new DateTimeImmutable())->setTimestamp($timestamp);`

Answer (score 25):

If you are using PHP `date()`, you can use this code to get the date, time, second, etc.

```
$time = time();               // you have 1299446702 in time
$year = $time/31556926 % 12;  // to get year
$week = $time / 604800 % 52;  // to get weeks
$hour = $time / 3600 % 24;    // to get hours
$minute = $time / 60 % 60;    // to get minutes
$second = $time % 60;         // to get seconds
```

Comment: How about leap year and second...?

Comment: `$year = date('Y', $time)`

Answer (score 23):

If anyone wants timestamp conversion directly to a DateTime object, there's a simple one-liner:

```
$timestamp = 1299446702;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timestamp);
```

Following @sromero comment, timezone parameter (the 3rd param in DateTime::createFromFormat()) is ignored when unix timestamp is passed, so the below code is unnecessary.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timestamp, new DateTimeZone('UTC'); // not needed, 3rd parameter is ignored
```

You may check PHP's manual for [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for more info and options.

Comment: Jus a comment about your last line of code: according to the manual page you link: 

"Note:

The timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the time parameter either contains a UNIX timestamp (e.g. 946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00)."

Comment: @sromero You have right. The timezone parameter is ignored in this case.

Answer (score 20):

```
$epoch = 1483228800;
$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");  // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output = 2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

In the examples above "r" and "Y-m-d H:i:s" are PHP date formats, other examples:

### Format  Output

```
r              -----    Wed, 15 Mar 2017 12:00:00 +0100 (RFC 2822 date)
c              -----    2017-03-15T12:00:00+01:00 (ISO 8601 date)
M/d/Y          -----    Mar/15/2017
d-m-Y          -----    15-03-2017
Y-m-d H:i:s    -----    2017-03-15 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this one:

```
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', 1541843467);
```

Comment: Hi there! It seems that this answer has already been proposed; see the top answer.

Comment: One line, perfect.

Answer (score 17):

Try it.

```
<?php
 $timestamp=1333342365;
 echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
   $mytimestamp = 1465298940;

   echo gmdate("m-d-Y", $mytimestamp);
```

Output :

> 06-07-2016

Answer (score 9):

Unless you need a custom date and time format, it's easier, less error-prone, and more readable to use one of the [built-in date time format constants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types):

```
echo date(DATE_RFC822, 1368496604);
```

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Answer (score 5):

`echo date("l M j, Y",$res1['timep']);`
This is really good for converting a unix timestamp to a readable date along with day. Example:
Thursday Jul 7, 2016

Comment: Similar answers are already posted, what is the plus of information in your answer?

Answer (score 5):

```
echo 'Le '.date('d/m/Y', 1234567890).' &agrave; '.date('H:i:s', 1234567890);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I have used this:
<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i a', $row['start_time']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers work properly if the default time zone of your PHP server is not GMT.

For example.  Consider this code that round trips a date to a timestamp and back.

```
 $d0 = new \DateTimeImmutable('1/1/2023');
 echo 'Formatted Jan 1, 2023 date = '.$d0->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
 $t0 = $d0->getTimestamp();
 echo 'Unix timestamp = '.$t0.'<br>';
 $d1 = new \DateTimeImmutable('@'.$t0);
 echo 'Date from timestamp = '.$d1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
```

You would expect the round tripped date to be identical to the original date. Wrong!  Output is as follows:

```
Formatted Jan 1, 2023 date = 2023-01-01 00:00:00
Unix timestamp = 1672556400
Date from timestamp = 2023-01-01 07:00:00
```

This is because the server time zone is America/Arizona. The documentation clearly states that if a DateTime or DateTimeImmutable object is created from a Unix timestamp, the default time zone or a provided time zone is ignored.  (Why?! Why?! Why?!)

To fix this, you need to add this...

```
 $d2 = $d1->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
 echo 'Corrected date from timestamp = '.$d2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
```

Which outputs this:

```
Corrected date from timestamp = 2023-01-01 00:00:00
```

This nails me about every year.  Just now I spent 2 hours trying to figure out why my times are all wrong.  I went to my test bench and behold! there is my solution to this problem from a year ago.  PHP.  pfffft.