# Getting date time from a string

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert timestamp to readable date/time PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php)

Given 1328520572 as a datetime string, 
how can i get the datetime in specific format from it ?

I'd like to use

```
str = '1328520572';
str_ret=datetime.Parse("M:D:Y H:M:S",str);
```

Comment: Give us a clue: what date/time do you think it should return?

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/SclLQW

Comment: please use the search function before asking questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '1328520572';
echo date("M:D:Y H:M:S", (int)$str);
```

But your date format is wrong, check the right format [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

Properly formatted `datetime`?

```
$unix = '1328520572';
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unix);
```

Answer (score 0):

$str_ret = date("m:d:Y H:i:s", $str);

Comment: and str will be a timestamp,
you also forgot the $ before variables ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = '1328520572';
$str_ret = date('M:D:Y H:M:S', strtotime($str));
```