# Working out PHP time

Tags: php, time

I've searched everywhere for an answer but I can't work it out:

```
if(time() > 1345219200) {
do something
}
```

When would that time be? I can't get my head around it

Comment: [`date`](http://php.net/date)?

Comment: You can convert a timestamp into a readable format like this: `echo date('r', 1345219200);` echos something like `Fri, 17 Aug 2012 16:00:00 +0000`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to readable date/time PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php)

Answer (score 7):

`time()` refers to the current time, and

`1345219200` refers to `Fri Aug 17 17:00:00 BST 2012`

PHP manual pages: [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

Comment: Any ideas what that'd be in BST?

Comment: See my answer for the GMT, so BST would be +1 hour from the date in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

PHP uses the unix time epoch to measure time. Meaning the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

The `time()` function returns the current time in seconds since the "epoch". So your if statement simply compares the current time against the 1345219200 time stamp which is (as @abhshkdz says) Fri, 17 Aug 2012 16:00:00 GMT. So until that time the statement will return `false` and nothing will happen.

You can read more about the PHP time function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo(date("D F d Y", 1345219200));
```

Fri August 17 2012