# Cannot figure out php date() timestamps for two timestamps

Tags: php, timestamp

With PHP, I am trying to convert a bunch of numbers into a a readable format, the thing is, I have no idea how/what format these are in or can be parsed in using the `date()` or `time()` functions in php. there are two of these as well.

(they're built from a total time spent online and time since last log-on)

```
onlinetime : 1544946 = 2w 3d 21h 9m
lastonline : 1397087222 = 1h 32m
```

does anyone know the way to get the two different times from the two different timestamps?

Comment: The first one is *probably* a number of seconds. The second is a unix timestamp. They can't be used in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Unix timestamp, take a look at [Convert timestamp to readable date/time PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php). The PHP documentation is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

For the online time, you could do modulo arithmetic to figure out the values for each, and then just make a string out of the result. Someone may have a nicer suggestion for this though.

Comment: Thank you! it turns out the first format was in seconds *facepalm* and the second one was in Epoch.

Answer (score 0):

I think John is right, the first is the number of seconds in the timespan listed.  And the second certainly looks like a unix timestamp to me.  So here's how you can get what you want from these sets of numbers:

1) For the first number, simply divide the number by the seconds in a given time span and use floor():

```
$timeElapsed = 154496; // in this case
$weeksElapsed = floor($timeElapsed / 604800);
$remainder = $timeElapsed % 604800;
$daysElapsed = floor($remainder / 86400);
etc...
```

2) For the second number, you can do the same thing by first getting the current timestamp and then subtracting the given timestamp from it:

```
$lastOnline = 1397087222; // again, in this case
$currentTimestamp = time();
$elapsedSinceLastLogin = $currentTimestamp - $lastonline;
$weeksSinceLastLogin = floor($elapsedSinceLastLogin / 604800);
etc...
```