# Converting timestamp into readable format

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I know this has been asked a million times before, but none of the other answers have actually given me what I need. I have a timestamp as follows:

> 2014-05-10T21:30:00+0200

How would I convert this to say:

> Gig is starting at 21:30pm on 05/10/14

I'm working with PHP. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to readable date/time PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php)

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert your `time` to `timestamp`.

```
$timestamp = strtotime("2014-05-10T21:30:00+0200");
```

Then Display it as you want.

```
echo date("h.m.Y", $timestamp);
```

Or you can use `DateTime` class

```
$objDateTime= new DateTime("2014-05-10T21:30:00+0200");
$objDateTime->format(DateTime::ISO8601); // Another way to get an ISO8601 formatted string
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an Atom date, not a timestamp. You probably want to do something like this:

```
function print_event_time($atom, $name='Gig', $verb='starting'){
  list($s1, $s2) = explode(',',date('g:ia,d/m/y', strtotime("$atom")));  
  echo sprintf('%s is %s at %s on %s',$name,$verb,$s1,$s2);
}

echo print_event_time('2014-05-10T21:30:00+0200');
 //> Gig is starting at 7:30pm on 10/05/14

echo print_event_time('2014-05-10T21:30:00+0200', 'Shindy', 'rollin');
 //> Shindy is rollin at 7:30pm on 10/05/14
```