# Troubles with converting PHP timestamp to local date string

Tags: php, date, timezone

I'm trying to convert a `linux server timestamp` to a `formatted local date` string.

The `$timestamp` is `1429800741`, and the `expected date string` is `"2015/4/23 14:52:21"`, but where I use `date("Y/n/j H:i:s", $timestamp)`, the result is `"2015/4/23 06:52:21"`, it's `8 hours slower`.

I checked my server with command line `"date -R"`, and it shows `"Thu, 23 Apr 2015 14:55:59 +0800"`.

In php, function `date_default_timezone_get() echo "Asia/Shanghai".`

It looks like all my timezone has been set correctly, why is the formatted string wrong ?

Anyone please help me, thanks!!!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I  added the $timestamp argument into the date() function, but I forgot to paste the right code here.

Comment: is this timestamp correct for those outpud dates, or there may occur a typo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to readable date/time PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php)

Comment: `1429800741` is `2015/04/23 14:52:21 +00:00`, [demo](https://eval.in/317675). **In what timezone do you wish your datetime to be?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting a proper time on my PC, but I believe this is a proper approach for your question, maybe you will work that out further:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimestamp('1429800741');
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Shanghai'));

echo $datetime->format('Y/n/j H:i:s P');
```

Comment: I tried you code, it didn't work, still 8 hours slower...    T_T

Answer (score -1):

Need to add the timestamp to the date function:

```
date("Y/n/j H:i:s", $timestamp);
```