# php timestamp to readable date not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to convert my timestamp to a readable date (going to be used in a sql query).

My code:

```
$date1 = date("d-m-Y",Input::get('van'));
return Input::get('van')."  ".$date1;
```

The timestamp:

```
1451602800000
```

the result

```
15-12-1966
```

When i try [this application](http://www.epochconverter.com/) the result of that timestamp is Thu, 31 Dec

```
2015 23:00:00 GMT
```

Which is what i was expecting.
What am i doing wrong that makes me get the wrong day-month year? the timestamp seems to be oke the code is the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php):

Adding:

```
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

dosn't change anything

Comment: What is Input::get('van')?

Comment: Its the value (from a get request) holding the exact timestamp. it could be any var holding that timestamp value.

Comment: Well, your 1451602800000 timestamp is for June 18 in the year 47969.

Comment: Brogan is that the date you get when entering it in the provided link? I get Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:
GMT: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 23:00:00 GMT

Comment: The unix timestamp is in seconds.

Comment: Go punch your timestamp into the panel on the right here. http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: Hey Sven, I'd just like to add this one extra comment. The link you gave does the calculation I've provided in my answer to display the proper timestamp. If you punch in that timestamp with the five 0's, you'll see a message in bold appear that says "Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:" If you remove three of the zero's, it will show the exact same date and time except that bold message will disappear. We take your number / 1000 because we are assuming that the timestamp you're providing is in milliseconds like the Epoch Converter page.

Answer (score 1):

Remove three zeros from the right of your timestamp. A Unix timestamp is represented in seconds, not milliseconds.

```
$date1 = date('d-m-Y', Input::get('van') / 1000);
return Input::get('van') . '  ' . $date1;
```

---

See the [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function for an example of an acceptable timestamp that can be used with the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use Laravel, so  this package it integrated:

https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

And try this tutorial to get up to speed:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon