# how to get local date from timestamp = 1574463600 in php mysql

Tags: php, timestamp, timezone

i am using sports api and i am getting matches schedule from api but the timestamp is UTC and i want to search match according to my localdate the timestamp is look like this 1574463600

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert timestamp to readable date/time PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@` along with the unix time to create a `DateTime` class.

```
<?php

$unixTime = 1574463600;

$date = new DateTime('@' . $unixTime);
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');  // outputs 22/11/2019
```

See it here https://3v4l.org/eoSU9

Read about `DateTime` here https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime