# how do you convert the "exp" jwt to proper date format(YYYY-MM-DD T HH:MM+02 00)

Tags: php, mysql, json, jwt

so i have been creating a user api using php and jwt and i am trying to output the exp date and time when testing in postman however i see that the exp value returns something like:

"message":"Access granted.","exp":1611315368"

how can i make it such that it gives me the date format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert timestamp to readable date/time PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php)

Comment: Its probally unix time format so you can use it like echo date('YYY-MM-DD H-m-s',exp), https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @Grumpy I can confirn, it is unix time format