# how to convert Integer values into timestamp format?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Integer column "duration_temp" that have values represent the duration in minutes, I want to copy those values in another column "duration" of type timestamp, I'm having the problem of how to convert those Int minutes into timestamps format, for example:
if a value in Int is set to 4 then I should convert it to yyyy-mm-dd 00:04:00.
is there a function that can do that or close from doing that?any suggestion would be appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert timestamp to readable date/time PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php)

Comment: You just have number of minutes and want to convert it into timestamp ? what about the year, month and day ?

Comment: If you want the date portion to default to today's date, then [`mktime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) might be what you're looking for, just pass a zero for hour + second arguments. But your question isn't totally clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding minutes to date time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169139/adding-minutes-to-date-time-in-php)

Comment: sorry I sould have added more infos, i have a column that includes the dates for every record I will use those dates to fill the date part in the convertion

Comment: This is still a bit ambiguous, as you are talking about columns. Do you by any chance might want to use SQL for this instead? As in you have timestamp in one column, minutes in another, so maybe you could just do something like this:
`UPDATE my_table SET duration = duration + duration_temp*60;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a duration in minutes. You could use `DateInterval` like this.

```
$yourDate = new DateTime('2021-01-01 00:00:00');
$durationInMinutes = 4;

$interval = new DateInterval("PT{$durationInMinutes}M");
$yourDate->add($interval);

echo $yourDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you just have minutes and want to make a timestamp from it with current date information, try this (after adding `use Carbon\Carbon;` in top of you file):

```
$minutes = 4;
return Carbon::create(now()->year, now()->month, now()->day, 0, $minutes)->toDateTimeString();
```

Answer (score 1):

As your integer column `duration_temp` is in **minutes**, you have to convert it to **seconds** before you can get the expected result.

Take your example :

> Int = 4 minutes => Int = 4 * 60 = 240 second

To finish :

```
date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", 240); // will give you 1970-01-01 00:04:00
```

Comment: Depending on the local settings of the server (time zone), a different result is provided with this code.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime accepts extensive [Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). This makes possible as an example:

```
$durationInMinutes = 67;

$date = date_create('2021-01-01 '.$durationInMinutes.' Minutes');
//or $date = new DateTime('2021-01-01 '.$durationInMinutes.' Minutes');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//2021-01-01 01:07:00
```

Also works correctly with negative minute numbers.